# Почему не подключается к удаленной БД с сервера хостера к БД на VPS?

Tags: mysql, python

Подскажите почему не подключается с сервера хостера к БД на VPS сервере. 
Вот этот скрипт работает с моего компа, даже без параметра connect_timeout.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

login = "serj3"
password = "12345678"

db = MySQLdb.connect(db='fatum', host="хх.хх.хх.хх", user="root", passwd="хххххххх", connect_timeout=150)
c = db.cursor()
add_gamer =  "INSERT INTO accounts(login, password) VALUES (%s,%s) ",(login,password)
c.execute(*add_gamer)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

. По документации 150 это секунды, но крутится секунд 10 и выдает ошибку 500. В логах пишут что не смог подключиться, время ожидания подключения истекло. _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'хх.хх.хх.хх\' (110 "Connection timed out")')

Answer (score 1):

Возможно на VPS у базы нужно данных разрешить удаленное подключение

Comment: я же пишу, что с моего компа всё работает.

Comment: @SergeyWhite , у сервера хостера возможно тоже есть настройка которая запрещает удаленное подключение, разрешает только подключение к локальной базе

Comment: выяснил в чём была проблема. фаервол у них не пропускал удаленное подключение к другой БД. спасибо за отклик